# What is the best way of making webservice secure

Tags: php, xcode, web-services, ipad, rest

I have been reading/googling for the last week on best approach to this issue/application.

I have an app that is bascially a database front end, currently it stores data locally, all works happily (available in the app store).

What i want to do next is store this data on a server.

(Before this i had no experience in server at all so everything from this point on from my own research and asumptions, if something is incorrect please point it out to me).

I decided that a RESTful webservice design would be best for what i wanted.
Basically intention is iPad/Android will be able to talk to web service, web service sits on top of a MySQL database, web service will receive strings, vidoes, photos.

My current situation is i can get the webservice to talk to the MySQL database, i can send simple requests from iPad for data (strings) and to post data (strings), (Still need to figure out best way of handling photos and videos, but thats a different issue).

**My Question:** What is the best way of making this web service Login/Secure.

The data is sensitive so has to be secure. Currently the user can't access the app without a username & password, but obeviously i need to take precations in the web service also.

I have done loads and loads of googling research and even topics on here i seem to be constantly seeing comments along the lines of "This method is out of date" etc.

It seems to be there are two fundamental approaches, 
1) Basically having a GUID which is configered on inital start up <-I think
2) On every request for data also transfering password/username.

Any help guidance would be greatfully recieved.

Thanks

P.S. Sorry about the essay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approaches to make your API secure.

- oAuth implementation to send and receieve data with authentication headers.
- SSL certicificates to make sure the communication between your server and client is encrypted. You can easily buy a private certificate for as low as $15/month.
- Hash database fields such as password. (Make sure NOT to use MD5 as it is not secured. Use SHA1 or SHA2 instead).
- Don't store user passwords in mobile applications, store some sort of hashed auth key, instead.

Answer (score 1):

- It is possible to encrypt and sign the data exchanged between the server and the client. For that you can generate your own trusted certificate for free. You'll have to look for the methods based on the technologies you are using. This will protect you against man in the middle attacks as an intruder can't read or alter the data.
- Any passwords you use in the code should be encrypted to protect against reverse engineering (at least for amateurs)
- Use key based encryption algoritms
- Capture all the exceptions, an error should never be transmitted to the client as it's a door to your system.
- Protect your wsdl file (if you have any) against public viewing.
- Validate your forms, the user shouldn't be able to inject special characters like "<",">","'","=","-"...

  This is what I can think of for now.